# AS3 - TextField: Embedded font

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

This code will not render text to the screen. Changing,

```
drawText.embedFonts = false;
```

Renders text, but font size doesn't modify or the color.

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.*;

public class DrawText extends Sprite {

    private var drawText:TextField;
    private var myFormat:TextFormat;

    [Embed(source="c:/windows/fonts/verdana.ttf", fontFamily="Verdana", embedAsCFF="false")]
    private var verdana:Class;
    public function DrawText(mX:int,mY:int){

        myFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana");
        myFormat.size = 32;
        myFormat.color = 0x00FFFF;

        drawText = new TextField();
        drawText.embedFonts = true;
        drawText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        drawText.selectable = false;
        drawText.type = "dynamic";
        drawText.multiline=true;
        drawText.wordWrap=true;
        drawText.x = 128;
        drawText.y = 128;
        drawText.text = "TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST";
        drawText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
        addChild(drawText);

    }//END constructor

}//END class

}//END package
```

It's really frustrating any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Flash Builder 4.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply `defaultTextFormat` before the setting of the `text` or use `TextField.setTextFormat` for the existed text

UPD:
As for the `embedFonts` you have to register font class before using:

```
Font.registerFont(verdana);
```

UPD2:

Example (modify code in the topic):

```
   //set defaultTextFormat before set text 
   //and use setTextFormat to format existed text 
   drawText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
   drawText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
   drawText.text = "TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST";
```

Comment: You just beat me to it! I just figured that out! Was driving me nuts! This is the answer but you replied so fast I can't mark it yet! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please write an example of this? thanks... i'm facing some issues

Answer (score 1):

You should use `drawText.setTextFormat(myFormat);`